# Codeigniter emailer not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

```
$this->load->library('email');
// set email data
$this->email->from($this->input->post('sender_email'), $this->input->post('sender_name'));
$this -> email -> set_mailtype("html");
$this->email->to('');
$this->email->reply_to($this->input->post('sender_email'), $this->input->post('sender_name'));
$this->email->subject('From: '.$this->input->post('sender_name'));

$this->email->message("<table><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>".$this->input->post('sender_name')."</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>".$this->input->post('sender_email')."</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>".$this->input->post('phone')."</td></tr><tr><td>Message:  </td><td>".$this->input->post('message')."</td></tr></table>");
$this->email->send();
// create a view named "succes_view" and load it at the end
redirect('contact?email_succ=1');
exit();
```

This is the code I'm using to send email from a form in CI and it works only when I use SMTP login along with this.

```
$this->load->library('email');
$config['protocol']    = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_port']    = '465';
$config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
$config['smtp_user']    = 'myemail@example.com';
$config['smtp_pass']    = 'emailpassword';
$config['charset']    = 'utf-8';
$config['newline']    = "\r\n";
$config['mailtype'] = 'html'; // or html
$config['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or     not      
$this->email->initialize($config);
```

Having this code right after loading the library solves the issue. But what's wrong with the default code that has been working all this time but suddenly stopped?

**UPDATE**: adding just this line `$this->email->initialize($config);` solves the issue, But why?.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982704/codeigniter-this-email-send-not-working-while-mail-does

Comment: @Mr.Web Yes, I did get the solution from that link earlier. But I'm wondering why the default setup isn't working. Any update in CI caused that?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know.. I'm now using v 3.0 and I have to check for that 'cause I didn't use it up to now.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
$config = array();
$config['useragent']           = "CodeIgniter";
$config['mailpath']            = "/usr/bin/sendmail"; // or "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
$config['protocol']            = "smtp";
$config['smtp_host']           = "localhost";
$config['smtp_port']           = "25";
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
$config['newline']  = "\r\n";
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->message = "Your Message";
$this->email->subject("Message Subject");
$this->email->from("user@gmail.com");
$this->email->to("admin@gmail.com");
$this->email->send();
```