# codeigniter email send successfully but email is not received in the inbox

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am trying to work on send emails with an attachment. My function works fine but mail is not received in the inbox. my function looks like:

```
<?php
public function career()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'docx|pdf';
    $config['max_size'] = '2000';
    $config['max_width']  = '';
    $config['max_height']  = '';
    $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;    
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $result = $this->upload->do_upload();
    if ($result)
    {
        $fileInfo=$this->upload->data();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('specialization', 'specialization', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'trim|required');
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->index();
        }
        else
        {
            $path =  base_url('assets/uploads/'.$fileInfo['file_name']);
            $specialization = $this->input->POST('specialization', TRUE);
            $name = $this->input->POST('name', TRUE);
            $email = $this->input->POST('email', TRUE);
            $this->load->library('email');
            $this->email->from($email, $name);
            $this->email->to('name@gmail.com');
            $this->email->subject('Resume');
            $this->email->message($specialization);
            $this->email->attach($path);
            $results=$this->email->send();
            if($results)
            {
                $this->index();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->index();
    }
}
?>

$this->email->send(); is working fine and get redirected to the $this->index(); function. but the email is not received. How to solve this?
```

Comment: are you trying to send the email in localhost?

Comment: no.. on the server

Comment: Check your junk mail?

Comment: Nothing its empty

Comment: Try:1) if($this->email->send()) {
        echo $this->email->print_debugger(); 
        echo "success";
    } else {            
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        echo "failed";
    } and also try to send it to your webmail account and check it there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982704/codeigniter-this-email-send-not-working-while-mail-does

Comment: I don't think $path should be base_url, it should be the server path of the file... `/home/yoursite/public_html/assets/uploads/filename.pdf`

Comment: I tried but nothing happened