# CodeIgniter Send Email doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I've created a sending of email using codeigniter. on the past months it was working fine. When I checked it again it doesn't send emails anymore.

Here's My code:

```
 public function send_mail($registration_info_id){

    $config_mail = $this->main_m->get_all('emails');
    $all_mails="";
        foreach($config_mail as $email){
            $all_mails.= $email['email'].',';
        }

    $supply_email = rtrim($all_mails,",");


    $registration_info = $this->main_m->get_where('registration_info', array('registration_info_id' => $registration_info_id));
    $personal_info = $this->flight_travel_request_m->personal_info_per_person($registration_info_id);
    $cc_details = $this->main_m->get_where('payment_credit_card_details', array('registration_info_id' => $registration_info_id));
    $full_name  = $personal_info['firstname']." ".$personal_info['lastname'];

    $data = array(
        'registration_info' => $registration_info,
        'personal_info' => $personal_info,
        'cc_details' => $cc_details
        );

    //$this->load->view('email_acknowledgement/acknowledgement', $data);
    $message=$this->load->view('email_acknowledgement/acknowledgement', $data, true);

    $this->load->library('email');

    $this->email->from('sample@site.com', 'SiteName');
    $this->email->to($personal_info['email'], $full_name); 
    $this->email->reply_to('sample@site.com', 'SiteName');
    $this->email->bcc($supply_email); 
    $this->email->subject('Arrival Departure Transportation Service');
    $this->email->message($message);    
    if(!empty($attachment)){$this->email->attach($attachment);}
    $this->email->set_mailtype('html'); 

    if($this->email->send())
     {
      echo 'Email sent.';
     }
     else
    {
     show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
}
```

it echoes the `Email Sent` however I cant receive any email on my email address.
it was working fine previously.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it worked fine previously, the problem probablly is not in the code, but somewhere in the environement. Check email server settings: user, password, ports, spam filters, other security issues...
Try to send to it to a different email address, different email server, to test.

Comment: yes sir it was working fine in the past... I've tried sending it on other email as well but they can't receive the email.... what's weird is that the method returns `Email Sent`. so probably there's nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: @MarcM I've tried creating a simple php mail function it works though... but the codeigniter mail function still doesn't send email.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982704/codeigniter-this-email-send-not-working-while-mail-does?noredirect=1&lq=1
There're several config suggestions to be taken in consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Please try it.

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['validate'] = 'FALSE';
```

I hope that works for you

And see this link [Codeigniter $this->email->send() not working while mail() does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982704/codeigniter-this-email-send-not-working-while-mail-does)

Comment: I happen to solve the problem, it seems that the Domain Email that the client provided doesn't exist yet, so I created a domain email and use it...

Comment: Why validation FALSE? @Md.Jewel Mia

Comment: this solution and the suggested link question's all solution are not working.